# Erro ao ler arquivo .xlsx no R

Tags: r, microsoft-excel

Tenho um arquivo `.xlsx` que necessito ler no R. A aba é variável, portanto, utilizo um código antes para verificar qual a aba mais recente, porém, ao usar a função `read_excel` do pacote `readxl`, retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Erro: `path` does not exist: ‘Dados/Previso~es Imperial College.xlsx’
```

Antes, estou utilizando um `setwd` para definir a pasta onde estão todos os arquivos. Dentro da pasta `COVID-19` existe uma pasta `Dados`. O que não estou entendendo é que a função `excel_sheets`, que é do mesmo pacote, consegue ler o arquivo normalmente.

Código que estou utilizando:

```
library(readxl)

setwd("~/GitHub/COVID-19") #Exemplo

abas <- length(excel_sheets("Dados/Previsões Imperial College.xlsx"))

aba <- excel_sheets("Dados/Previsões Imperial College.xlsx")[abas]

dia <- read_excel("Dados/Previsões Imperial College.xlsx", 
                  sheet = aba, range = "B1:B1", col_names = FALSE)
```

Link da planilha: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EB23dikhYUMnaSdQLTA8Bb00FhrdVyJ-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Tente renomear o arquivo, retirando espaços e letras acentuadas do seu nome.

Comment: Estava buscando uma explicação para uma função do pacote ler o arquivo e a outra não. Mas obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a última escrita do nome da planilha tem algum caracter escondido, que causa o erro de caminho. Veja que quando eu seleciono o 2º nome, o 1º nome aparece selecionado, e o 3º não:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então basta você deletar e reescrever o nome da planilha (ou copiar das anteriores).

Comment: Obrigado! Não tinha notado esse detalhe.